# httplib equivalent for C

Tags: python, c

Is there a library like Python's httplib for C?

I am asking because I want to write a C program that creates an HTTPSConnection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libcurl is indead the most famous, but there are also a lot of alternatives [here](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/competitors.html).